# Un VBS para borrar logs borra todos excepto Setup

Tags: archivo, registro-windows, vbs

Tengo un problema con este *VBS* que permite salvar y borrar los *log* del sistema, funciona con todos menos con el *log* ***Setup***.

¿Por qué no se borra ese *log* y cómo puedo borrarlo?

```
' Back Up and Clear an Event Log

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Backup)}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile where LogFileName='Setup'")

For Each objLogfile in colLogFiles
    errBackupLog = objLogFile.BackupEventLog("c:\scripts\Setup.evt")
    If errBackupLog <> 0 Then        
        Wscript.Echo "The Application event log could not be backed up."
    Else
        objLogFile.ClearEventLog()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Si es que aparece algún error puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/329432/edit) pegando el texto del error. Quizás para solucionarlo debas abrir el programa en modo administrador, deben ser los permisos del sistema o los permisos del archivo que no se puede eliminar... Alguna vez usé [_Unlocker_](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) para eliminar archivos rebeldes.

Comment: Siempre lo ejecuto como admin pero nada no funciona de verdad que no se ya que hacer. Con los de más log si funciona.

Comment: Qué extraño, si aparece algún error sugiero que edites tu pregunta.

Comment: ArtEze , si aparece algún error sugiero que edites tu pregunta? no entiendo que error es ese, a usted de funciona ese vbs.

Comment: No, yo no tengo _Windows_, tengo _Linux_, por lo que no puedo probar el _VBS_, sin embargo, si al ejecutar tu _VBS_ te aparece algún mensaje o algún error, sugiero copiar el texto y pegarlo en la pregunta. En caso de no poder copiarlo, escribirlo a mano o de última pegar una captura de pantalla. Además sugiero que muestres una captura de pantalla mostrando que el archivo **Setup** no está borrado y en qué ruta del sistema está, o cómo es que te diste cuenta que no está borrado. De esa manera otros usuarios que sepan del tema podrían ayudarte.

Comment: Bueno todavía no estoy muy diestro con es.stackoverflow.com nos se subir img pero he comprobado de que existen el log Setup en el sistema y no se muestra ningún error al ejecutar el vbs.

Comment: Guardas la imagen en alguna carpeta del sistema y luego al editar la pregunta tocas el ícono de [la imagen con las montañitas, o tocas ``Control+G`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swgOf.png). En esta captura que pongo es la imagen del centro.